# How to make Only one device login at a time in AWS Userpool iOS?

Tags: ios, aws-userpools

I have an application in which user can log in/signup with Mobile Number and OTP. I have used AWS UserPool for this functionality.

But I want that Only one user can log in at a time.

Suppose in device 1 user login with the mobile number: +9197XXX XXXXX
then if in device 2 user login with the same mobile number: +9197XXX XXXXX

Then the first device should be logged out automatically.

How should i achieve this in AWS Userpool??

Comment: you need to reset device token from server side..

Comment: Yes, we can do that but after that, we have to sent silent notification to first log in user and make force signout. But I want to know is there any method in AWS which do this scenario.

Comment: not require just clear all device token and just add new token at login time.. after other in call api or web-request at that time device token not match and then that get error..

Comment: I am not calling any APIs. I read/write data from dynamoDB directly.